# Turn off the minifier HTML in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

My project uses Nuxt and Pug, I would like to turn off minification HTML To normally follow the SSR How to do it?

I tried to do it like this!
*nuxt.config.js*

```
build: {
      html: {
          minify:{
              collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
              decodeEntities: true,
              minifyCSS: true,
              minifyJS: false,
              processConditionalComments: true,
              removeEmptyAttributes: true,
              removeRedundantAttributes: true,
              trimCustomFragments: true,
              useShortDoctype: true,
              removeComments: true,
              preserveLineBreaks: true,
              collapseWhitespace: true
          }
      },
  },
```

Comment: `to normally follow the SSR`? What do you mean by that? The source code should not be impacted by pug.

Comment: Right now my code looks like one line, but I would like to keep hyphens and tabs